# TabControl Focus with Desktop 2D application

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

i having start with FireMonkey XE4 desktop 2D, but i having problems with `TTabControl` and <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

If i have 2 `TEdit` controls in the form or `TPanel` and i press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the focus got to next control, but i put 2 `TEdit` controls inside of a `TTabControl` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, no having change the focus to next `TEdit`.

I not understand how make this linking, same using the event KeyDown or KeyPress i not get positives results.

Exist other `TPageControl` or `TTabControl` for free?

Or, how create a new Page/TabControl from of a `TPanel` or Build a new?

Comment: Please learn to use the Shift key properly. Things typed in CAPS FOR NO REASON are harder to read. Thanks.

Comment: I can confirm this problem and is probably a bug?